# Architecture advice required - Client-Cloud - Hardware Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, amazon-web-services, client-server, cloud

We are designing an application that will be predominantly cloud-based. Virtually all of the features of the application will be .NET MVC 4.

However, there are two elements of the application that are required to drive two specific pieces of hardware, both via USB.

We will create the necessary drivers for both these hardware devices, for both Mac and Windows.

The problem is that the browser-based application needs to talk to the drivers that are installed and running on the client end.

This is a multi-site roll-out so the server side needs to communicate with different clients in real time.

For example, let's look at a pretend scenario to illustrate the problem.

"Cloud-based security system, hosted externally. Needs to talk to a mag lock on a door in a specific building."

The drivers will be running as Daemons or Services on the client PC/Mac.

I'm happy for the communication to be between back-end application running on server and the driver *OR* the front-end web app (java/html) to talk to the driver (if that is possible).

It also needs to work cross-browser and cross-platform, so Flash, Silverlight and ActiveX are out of the equation (luckily!!)

What would be a robust, scalable and performant solution? There needs to be very little lag time between the request being made on the browser to the command hitting the device driver. It wouldn't be acceptable for instance to issue a command in the web app that then takes 10 seconds to reach the driver.

So we need some kind of reliable client-server service bus that can work across the cloud quickly.

Consideration: We're considering AWS as the hosting environment. Does AWS have a client-server service bus in the shape required for this architecture? If I did go the Amazon AWS route, would this do what I need: http://aws.amazon.com/sns/ ?

Another consideration: Could JavaScript trigger something on the client that could be picked up by the Daemon/Service? That would be a really simple solution because there would be virtually no latency. I know that there are a number of security restrictions (for obvious reasons) so I don't know what JavaScript would be capable of doing on the client. It would simply need to send an XML command to my running service.

Hope somebody can advise.

Comment: Could I simply use the WCF callback functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this be a good use of something like RabbitMq? The web clients talk to RabbitMq, which talks to the appropriate on-site-clients?

I don't know about SNS but it looks like a similar thing to rabbit. If you're hosting on Amazon it's probably the way to go.

Having the web client talk to the driver client puts too much responsibility on the web client IMO. Let it just have to deal with talking to a message broker and let that deal with informing the subscribers.

Note: I'm no expert on this but as nobody wiser has posted I felt this was worth a post. Basically, I think your initial instinct (Amazon SNS) is right.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I've never heard of RabbitMq before - had a quick look and it seems interesting, especially since it's open source, cross-platform and appears to have lots of support and tools. Appreciate the heads up on this.